# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

> Input string was not in a correct format.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 30:                 lbl_userName.Text = objReader.Item(0) & " " & objReader.Item(1)
>   Line 31:                 lbl_resumeHead.Text = objReader.Item(3)
>   Line 32:                 lbl_experience.Text = Convert.ToInt32(objReader.Item(4))

How to display an `Integer` value from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Convert.ToInt32(objReader.Item(4))
```

This assumes that the value coming from the database is convertable to an integer. If it's an string that can't be parsed, `DbNull`, etc. it will fail.

More examples in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Your `objReader.Item(4)` does not contain a valid integer value - it may be `DBNull.Value`, `String.Empty`, a floating point value or something else:

```
Convert.ToInt32(objReader.Item(4))
```

By the way - instead of using ordinals you should use field names - this ensure you are using the correct field.

If you know the field name, use it:

```
Convert.ToInt32(objReader("MyIntegerField"))
```